# dojo updated causes strange errors

Tags: javascript, dojo

I recently updated my project to dojo version 1.6.2 from 1.6.1 now I keep getting strange errors without any code changed.

Chrome error console:

```
Error parsing in _ContentSetter#Setter_DIV_0 
 /etermin/js/dojo-release-1.6.2/dojo/../dijit/layout/ContentPane.js:203
Error undefined running custom onLoad code: This deferred has already been resolved 
/etermin/js/dojo-release-1.6.2/dojo/../dijit/layout/ContentPane.js:142
```

Firefox error console:

```
dojo.js (vrstica 324)
Error parsing in _ContentSetter#Setter_DIV_0
Error: Could not load class 'dijit.form.FileringSelect

dojo.js (vrstica 372)
Error undefined running custom onLoad code: This deferred has already been resolved
```

There is a problem in the dojo.js file: If I change it back to 1.6.1 it makes things work. But I want to use 1.6.2 version

Plaease help and advise

UPDATE: 
Something strange that I've found:

```
  var p = new dijit.MenuItem({
        label: "cut",
    })

  p.onClick = function() {
            dojo.xhrGet({
//some ajax call
});
}
```

Doesn't work. But if I put just one simple alert before the ajax it works.

```
 p.onClick = function() {
alert("123");
                dojo.xhrGet({
    //some ajax call
    });
}
```

Comment: Make sure you load all of your dependencies before you use them in your Widget templates.

Comment: I have them loaded at the start of the page. Does maybe this has todo something with Ajax?

Comment: If it works by putting an alert in it, then usually you have some kind of a timing issue where certain asynchronous parts of your code get mixed up. Deferreds also have things to do with asynchronous requests, so there might be a design issue. Can you post your XHR request too?

Comment: Changing my request to be sync did not help

Comment: It is not only the request... . It's your code. There are two indicators that there is an issue with your asynchronous code, the `alert()` that is working and the error message containing a `Deferred`. This usually means that you are calling something that doesn't exist yet, or you're doing something too many times. Often this means there is a structural problem in your code which can't be fixed by providing a few code snippets (if you can call these "code snippets" already).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you update your Version to 1.9? Sooner or later the legacy dojo won't work anymore and in the Google Hosted librarys i found no Version 1.6.2
Have a look:
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide
Is it still available? Where do you get the dojo.js from?

To prevent the timing Issue of the Menu, you can define the onClick when you
define your MenuItem.

Have a look :

```
var p = new dijit.MenuItem({
    label: "Menu Item With an icon",
    iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut",
    onClick: function(){alert('i was clicked')}
}));
```

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Updating from 1.6 to 1.7+ would require an entire rewrite due to the structural differences between the versions, no? Perhaps that's not possible in their case.

Comment: At the rate at which dojo is getting developed, support for 1.6 will be nearly non existent. You can still upgrade safely until 1.8 without much break because the global dojo, dijit and dojox is defined and will be removed only in dojo 2

Answer (score 1):

> **This is reported as a bug.**
>
> **Look [here](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17400) for the bug report**..
>
> ***You have to patch your dojo version or Upgrade it to 1.8 or later to fix it.***
>
> > **If you know what you are playing with you can fix it manually.**
> >
> > **The patch is on [*here*](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/commit/fc262d0d589c490cdd671791f1546a4665ed69c6).**
>
> **You can manually apply this to your current dojo build to fix it.**

Comment: I tried to use latest code from 1.6 branch in git that has this change applied but unfortunately it does not solve the problem.